# Steps to configure Mongodb to nodeclipse

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodeclipse

Hi i have installed MongoDB on windows 8 and followed these steps `(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_5mj3-_uJQ)` for installation, I done installation successfully.

Now I want to configure it into Nodeclipse please provide configuration steps

Answer (score 1):

first you need to install mondodb in your machine.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

and run

> mongod.exe

file it will be located in your installed bin folder

> C:\mongodb\3.2\bin

follow this sample code for connection

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports = {
     dbOperation : function() {
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
    /*insert*/
    if(!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");
        db.collection('user').insert({"name":"raghu", "age": "26", "qualification" : "B.E"},function(error,result){

        if(!error)
            console.log("data saved", result);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
        })
    }

    /*fetch*/
    if(!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");
      db.collection('user').find({"name":"raghu"}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        console.log("result", result);
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    }

    /*#update*/
    if(!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");
      db.collection('user').update({"age":"26"}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        console.log("result", result + "err", err);
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
    }
}
```

'user' is collection (table) name and 'test' is database name

Answer (score 0):

If you want GUI for MongoDB Nodeclipse as in https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/ does not give it.
There is only primitive runner of `.js` script with `mongo` client.

Check GitHUb issues, and decide what you really want to archive.